# How do I extract items which are in a list from python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, maps

I am quite new to python and I am struggling with this particular question.

I have the follow script:

```
landmask_regions = 
   'Africa': ['mask_M01.map', 'mask_M02.map', 'mask_M03.map', \
        'mask_M05.map', 'mask_M06.map', 'mask_M07.map', 'mask_M08.map', \
        'mask_M09.map'], \
   'Asia': ['mask_M04.map', 'mask_M05.map', 'mask_M10.map', 'mask_M11.map', \
        'mask_M12.map', 'mask_M13.map', 'mask_M14.map', 'mask_M15.map', \
        'mask_M16.map', 'mask_M17.map', 'mask_M18.map', 'mask_M19.map', \
        'mask_M20.map', 'mask_M21.map', 'mask_M22.map', 'mask_M23.map'], \
   'Europe': ['mask_M26.map', 'mask_M28.map', 'mask_M32.map', 'mask_M33.map', \
        'mask_M34.map'], \
   'N-America': ['mask_M25.map', 'mask_M35.map', 'mask_M36.map', 'mask_M37.map', \
        'mask_M38.map', 'mask_M39.map', 'mask_M40.map', 'mask_M41.map', \
        'mask_M42.map', 'mask_M43.map', 'mask_M44.map', 'mask_M45.map', 'mask_M46.map'], \
   'Australia': ['mask_M47.map', 'mask_M48.map', 'mask_M49.map'], \
   'S-America': ['mask_M24.map', 'mask_M50.map', 'mask_M51.map', \
        'mask_M52.map', 'mask_M53.map']}
```

So this script is a dictionary which is divided into continents, and for each continents it includes maps of certain regions.
Now I want to be able to read these maps for these occassions;

1. Read all the maps of the whole world all together
2. Read all the maps of one region, for example just 'Africa' or 'Asia' etc.
3. Read one specific region within a continent, say only mask_M08.map

How am I supposed to arrange a script which is able to do all of that?
I'm a bit stuck on this.

Comment: You should learn a bit about dicts: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "read a map"

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.
SO is an archive of specific programming questions; you appear to be looking for individual tutelage in how to analyze a problem and turn it into an algorithm.  This suggests that you're on the wrong site for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just get an input from the user, and then decide what to do.

For instance, you could accept:

- the special string `whole_world` which would select all the maps from all continents,
- any content, e.g. `Africa`, `Asia`, `Europe`,
- any individual map, ending in `.map`.

So, in Python, this would look like:

```
choice = input('which maps would you like to read?')
if choice == 'whole_world':
    maps = sum(landmask_regions.values(), [])
elif choice in landmask_regions:
    maps = landmask_regions[choice]
elif choice.endswith('.map'):
    maps = [choice]
#code to read map and do whatever...
```

---

So when `whole_world` is entered, the `maps` list contains the names of all maps:

```
['mask_M01.map', 'mask_M02.map', 'mask_M03.map', 'mask_M05.map', 'mask_M06.map', 'mask_M07.map', 'mask_M08.map', 'mask_M09.map', 'mask_M04.map', 'mask_M05.map', 'mask_M10.map', 'mask_M11.map', 'mask_M12.map', 'mask_M13.map', 'mask_M14.map', 'mask_M15.map', 'mask_M16.map', 'mask_M17.map', 'mask_M18.map', 'mask_M19.map', 'mask_M20.map', 'mask_M21.map', 'mask_M22.map', 'mask_M23.map', 'mask_M26.map', 'mask_M28.map', 'mask_M32.map', 'mask_M33.map', 'mask_M34.map', 'mask_M25.map', 'mask_M35.map', 'mask_M36.map', 'mask_M37.map', 'mask_M38.map', 'mask_M39.map', 'mask_M40.map', 'mask_M41.map', 'mask_M42.map', 'mask_M43.map', 'mask_M44.map', 'mask_M45.map', 'mask_M46.map', 'mask_M47.map', 'mask_M48.map', 'mask_M49.map', 'mask_M24.map', 'mask_M50.map', 'mask_M51.map', 'mask_M52.map', 'mask_M53.map']
```

and when a continent like `Africa` is entered, the `maps` list contains just the maps from that continent:

```
['mask_M01.map', 'mask_M02.map', 'mask_M03.map', 'mask_M05.map', 'mask_M06.map', 'mask_M07.map', 'mask_M08.map', 'mask_M09.map']
```

and when a specific map is entered, the `maps` list contains just that map:

```
['mask_M01.map']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I figured it out thanks to this!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you will want methods that call one another to complete each task you outlined. THat is, taking your list:

1. Read all the maps together
2. Read all the maps of one region.
3. Read one specific region within a continent

Let's do it from the bottom up, because it will be easier to work that way:

```
def read_map(mapp):
    """reads a .map file (arg is not map because map is a keyword)"""
    <map reading code>

def read_one_continent(continent, region):
     """Reads all maps for a given region"""
     print("Reading " + continent)
     for mapp in region:
         read_map(mapp)

def read_world(world):
    """reads all of the maps in the world"""
    for continent, maps in world:
        read_one_continent(continent, maps)
```

This way, you have a function to read an individual map, a function to read a group of them (e.g. a continent's maps list) and then a function for the whole thing! You could also put these into one big function, but this is probably more readable.

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me! I think I figured it out now.